# Azure App Service - How can I retrieve standard output in the Logs page?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-log-analytics

I am struggling to get the standard output of my App Service Linux webapp queried in the "Logs" page.
**All the AppService*Logs tables are empty.**
This is a NodeJS web server exposing an Angular web app.
Any hints ?

Thank you

Screenshot of the logs page with empty AppServiceAppLogs table:

[image: Screenshot of the logs page with empty AppServiceAppLogs table]

Answer (score 1):

For Linux webapp, **AppServiceAppLogs only support Java SE & Tomcat**. So, when you open AppServiceAppLogs table it is empty.

[image]

For more details, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-diagnostic-logs#supported-log-types).

Comment: Okay but what about the other Log types (AppServiceConsoleLogs, AppServiceHTTPLogs, AppServicePlatformLogs...) ? These ones are also empty.